# What is indigo bleach?

Tags: nouns

Does the bleach here refers to a blue dye, but less blue one, as some of the blue has been removed?

The rain seeped into the gap between the health sandals and her feet, just like it was seeping into everything else. Kerala was steeped in water, as if someone had pushed it in and pulled it out, like her mother used to steep white clothes in indigo bleach in a plastic bucket in their backyard. People were prepared, as they should be, in a state where it rained six months a year.

Comment: Indigo bleach, believe it or not, refers to bleach made with indigo, which plant  produces a dark blue dye.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So you're saying the indigo bleach, which is made with indigo, is meant to make the white clothes even whiter?

Comment: @Clare Can you support that? How do you make bleach out of indigo? I believe it refers to a strong beach water solution in which indigo dye can be dissolved.

Comment: I think you should ask the author. Not all beach is made from white bleach powder. But blue based beach is used in the hair coloring industry. That doesn't seem to fit here. Maybe the author is calling indigo dye indigo bleach for   some reason.

Comment: Relevant tangentially: ["Meaning of blue bag"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/373201/meaning-of-blue-bag/373262#373262)

Answer (score 1):

**[Indigo bleach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indigo_dye)** is a particular dye used for making bluejeans, or **denim**.

The passage you're quoting from uses the word "blue" frequently, probably for symbolic or literary reasons.

> The parking lot she'd just walked through where covered in **blue** and silver rain covers, umbrella covers stuck out...
>
> The colour of her salwarkurta was the same as the board, a deep midnight **blue**.

The author may have intended to use **blue** because of its common metaphorical implication of *loneliness* or *isolation*.

Answer (score -1):

> Indigo is a challenging dye because it is not soluble in water. To be dissolved, it must undergo a chemical change (reduction). Reduction converts indigo into "white indigo" (leuco-indigo). When a submerged fabric is removed from the dyebath, the white indigo quickly combines with oxygen in the air and reverts to the insoluble, intensely colored indigo. When it first became widely available in Europe in the 16th century, European dyers and printers struggled with indigo because of this distinctive property.

from Wikipedia "Indigo Dye" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indigo_dye

Comment: Reduction means mixed with bleach (or something like it), which is an oxidizer that strips some oxygen from the indigo dye, converting it into a soluble substance???